# Mod negative numbers in SQL just like excel

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having trouble replicating the mod function in SQL sever.

In excel, mod (-3, 7) = 4.  But in SQL,  -3 % 7 = -3

Am I using % wrong, or does SQL  do mod differently?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will give a result between 0 and n - 1 for both positive and negative values of x:

```
((x % n) + n) % n
```

Comment: My friend just pointed out that a shorter version would be  (n + x) % n

Comment: @TomHalladay: That works for x >= -n but will still give a negative result for x < -n.

Comment: @MarkByers It depends, on Oracle I get the good result because the modulo implementation never returns less than -n...

Answer (score 2):

Well, [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is done on [equivalence classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of integers, so neither Excel nor any RDBMS is "doing `%` wrong".  If you want a representative between 0 and 6, though, you can always do

```
select (-3 % 7) + 7;
```

Comment: The only problem is, if my value is 0, I need a result of 0

Comment: Wait, so you've got a pair of integers `m` and `n` such that `m` is congruent to 0 mod `n`, but `select m % n` is returning something other than zero?

Comment: @JackManey : Your answer in `(m % n) + n`, this gives `(0 % n) + n = n` where the OP wants it to equal `0`.  That's a sub-set of the reasons why MarkByers' answer has an additional `% n`.