# How can I calculate modulo in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark world and I would like to calculate an extra column with integers modulo in Pyspark. I have not find this operator in build in operators.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 23):

You can simply use the `%` operator between columns, as you would in normal python:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame([(6,3), (7, 3), (13,6), (5, 0)], ["x", "y"])
df.withColumn("mod", col("x") % col("y")).show()

#+---+---+----+
#|  x|  y| mod|
#+---+---+----+
#|  6|  3|   0|
#|  7|  3|   1|
#| 13|  6|   1|
#|  5|  0|null|
#+---+---+----+
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the spark built-in function [`mod`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#mod) or [`%`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#_2) operator with SQL syntax:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

# using mod function
df.withColumn("mod", expr("mod(x, y)")).show()

# using SQL %
df.withColumn("mod", expr("x % y")).show()
```

Comment: Warning for other users that modulo in pyspark can return negative results; the same behavior as with SQL, but different from the mathematical definition and the python behavior. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10472783/5675094

Comment: @mimocha thanks for this comment! I couldn't figure out why my numbers started becoming negative!