# How to convert radians to degrees where 0° is north

Tags: sql, degrees, radians

### Technology

MySQL

### Problem

Given is a radian value that defines the direction.

This radian can be easily converted to degrees (f.e. 1 radian = 57.296°).
But this would result in the following:

- 0° would match East
- 90° would match North
- 180° would match West
- ...

### Desired outcome

When given a radian value the degree is returned where the result is the following:

- 0° would match North
- 90° would match East
- 180° would match South
- 270° would match West
- ...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

### Degrees

The formula to convert a degree where 0° = East and going counterclockwise to degrees where 0° = North and going clockwise is the following:

> F(c) = (-(c-90)) % 360

c = input in degrees
F(c) = output in degrees

This can be translated to SQL as following:

> IF(IF(((-(DEGREES(@input)-90))%360) > 0, ((-(DEGREES(@input)-90))%360), (((-(DEGREES(@input)-90))%360)+360)))

@input = value in radians

*The if statement is present because the modulo (%) of a negative value in SQL would result in a negative value (see [Mod negative numbers in SQL just like excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472783/mod-negative-numbers-in-sql-just-like-excel) for more details)*

### Radians (Theta)

The formula to convert a radian where 0 = Easy and going counterclockwise to a radian where 0 = North and going clockwise is the following:

> F(c) = ((-(c+π)) % 2π) - π/2

c = input in radians
F(c) = output in radians

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP and the rest of us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Hi, my exsuses. This is for MySQL.